# Creating a desktop icon

Tags: desktop-icons

Following

[How to create a desktop icon on Ubuntu or Debian based systems](https://amalj07.medium.com/how-to-create-a-desktop-icon-on-ubuntu-or-debian-based-systems-333c82464683)

I created

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Isabelle
Comment=The Isabelle Theorem Prover
Exec="/home/user/Isabelle2022/bin/isabelle jedit %U"
Icon=/home/user/Isabelle2022/lib/logo/isabelle_transparent-128.png
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Isabelle
Type=Application
Categories="Theorem prover"
MimeType=text/thy
```

in `~/.local/share/applications/isabelle.desktop` .

But even after logout the icon did not appear on my desktop.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Put it in your login name home desktop dir and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your `.desktop` file in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory makes it appear in your menus and not on the Desktop.  You will have to copy it to your `~/Desktop` directory if you want it to appear on the Desktop.

Also, the `Categories=` line is where you want the icon to appear.  i.e. `Categories=System` will make your icon appear in the System applications menu.  Here are the categories you can choose from:  https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: That basically solved the problem. I had to do a few things afterwards: giving execution right to the file and then right-click on the icon and choosing Allow launching.